# Reactjs: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope with script: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script

Tags: reactjs

I run into error: "TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:"Port Number"/') with script ('http://localhost:"Port Number"/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script" when trying to config my Firebase messaging.
I am using airframe-dashboard v 0.1.0, so there is no public folder. So I try creating one like this:

[image]

My firebase-messaging-sw.js:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/database";
import 'firebase/messaging';

var firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "xxxx",
   authDomain: "xxxx",
   projectId: "myhealthqlpkv1",
   storageBucket: "xxxx",
   messagingSenderId: "xxxxx",
   appId: "xxxx",
   measurementId: "xxxx"
 };
 // Initialize Firebase
firebase.default.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// var db = firebase.default.database().ref();

const messaging = firebase.default.messaging();
export default messaging;
```

In my Login.js, I try to register and getToken:

```
import messaging from "../../../public/firebase-messaging-sw"
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js")
    .then(function(registration) {
      console.log("Registration successful, scope is:", registration.scope);
      messaging.getToken({vapidKey: 'xxxx', serviceWorkerRegistration : registration })
        .then((currentToken) => {
          if (currentToken) {
            console.log('current token for client: ', currentToken);
            localStorage.setItem('registrationToken', currentToken);
  
            // Track the token -> client mapping, by sending to backend server
            // show on the UI that permission is secured
          } else {
            console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
  
            // shows on the UI that permission is required 
          }
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
          // catch error while creating client token
        });  
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Service worker registration failed, error:"  , err );
    }); 
  }
```

Now I run into the above error, please help me with this !!!